# scala code to pull specific columns from a text file

Tags: scala

I am using below code to write few columns of a text file to a another file but the file size is 203. when I am using substring is giving below exception. can any one help to get it.

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 207"

```
object MO3AS160 {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val inputdata2 = scala.io.Source.fromFile("/C:/Users/rkolipa/Desktop/scala/test/MO3AS150.txt")
    val outputdata1 = new File("/C:/Users/rkolipa/Desktop/scala/test/MO3AS160.txt")
    val writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputdata1))
    val Indata=inputdata2.getLines().toArray
    for (k <- 0 until  Indata.size){
      var string1 = Indata(k).substring(149, 207)
      var string2 = Indata(k).substring(1, 20)
      var string3 = Indata(k).substring(22, 31)
      var string4 = Indata(k).substring(32, 102)
      var string5 = string1+" "+string2+" "+string3+" "+string4
      println(string5)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're taking a substring (`string1`) from a line that doesn't have at least 207 characters.

Comment: What is the specification of the file format? You are clearly not reading the format properly but it is impossible to say why without knowing what the format is.

Comment: If you have any control over the structure of the file, you should use a delimiter to separate the different values rather than hardcoding lines. On common example is to use commas (CSV files)

Comment: It is text file and it have 207 characters in each row. Seems substring is not supporting to pull columns if column start after 170 position so I am getting error.

Comment: What do you mean by "but the file size is 203."? 203 what? Also, Lists and things like that are zero-indexed, meaning that if there are 207 items they are referenced as item 0 to item 206. Are you sure that you want to have 207 in the `substring` section for string1 if there are 207 characters?

Comment: Number of lines in the csv is 203 but how you supposed to do subString(149, 207)? How do you know that there are at least 207 character in one line?

Comment: I changed the file to pipe delimited and I used below code now I am able to get the data


var string9 = outdata(k)(22)

Thanks you.